# Mysql JSON path extract by main query value

Tags: mysql, json, select, subquery

Table: infos

```
id     | info
------ | ------
1      | {"v1": "test", "v2": "work"}
```

Table: my_data

```
id     | name     | info_id
------ | ------   | ------
1      | john     | 2
2      | peter    | 1
3      | luc      | 2
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
name     | art
------   | ------
john     | work
peter    | test
luc      | work
```

My problem is i do not know how to use the value from main query as json path.

Right now i have this:

```
SELECT a.name, (SELECT info->>"$.v1" AS art FROM infos AS b) FROM my_data AS a
```

For sure this shows for all "test"

The query must be something like this:

```
SELECT a.name, (SELECT info->>CONCAT("$.v", a.info_id) AS art FROM infos AS b) FROM my_data AS a
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can we just check which version of MySQL you're using? May be I'm 'old school' (I am), but I'd be sorely tempted to *not* store json data.

Comment: Sure, the version is 5.7.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following (adjust as needed):

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.19    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_data`, `infos`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `infos` (
    ->   `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `info` JSON NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_data` (
    ->   `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   `info_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `infos`
    ->   (`info`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('{"v1": "test", "v2": "work"}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `my_data`
    ->   (`name`, `info_id`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('john', 2),
    ->   ('peter', 1),
    ->   ('luc', 2);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `md`.`name`,
    ->   JSON_UNQUOTE(
    ->     JSON_EXTRACT(
    ->       `i`.`info`,
    ->       CONCAT('$.v', `md`.`info_id`)
    ->     )
    ->   ) `art`
    -> FROM
    ->   `my_data` `md`
    ->   INNER JOIN `infos` `i` ON `i`.`id` = 1;
+-------+------+
| name  | art  |
+-------+------+
| john  | work |
| peter | test |
| luc   | work |
+-------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ahu951t4u3sksguoXF16YG/0).

Comment: Wow, thats it. Quite easy way. 
Nice.